# WriteBuildMessage not displayed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, tfsbuild, build-definition

Consider this simple msbuild script (xaml):

```
<Activity xmlns=[....]>
  <Sequence>
    <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage Message="Test message"/>
    <mtbwa:WriteBuildWarning Message="Test warning"/>
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

I have a tfs build definition based on this script.
When I queue a new build in tfs, the warning is displayed under "view log", the message is *not displayed*.

What do you think of that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is approx. a *minimal* workflow xaml file that works:

```
<Activity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
          xmlns:mtbwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow">
  <Sequence>
    <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage Importance="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.High]"
                             Message="Test WriteBuildMessage Importance High"/>
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

Default tfsbuild verbosity for logging in *view log* is *normal* but this will not display `BuildMessageImportance.Normal`, only `High`.

Another *gotcha* is that you have to click the button *Refresh* for the build process template in it's build definition under item *Process*.

This is a minimal workflow example that works including the `BuildVerbosity` property.

```
<Activity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
          xmlns:mtbw="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow"
          xmlns:mtbwa="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow"
          xmlns:this="clr-namespace:TfsBuild"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          x:Class="TfsBuild.Process"
          this:Process.Verbosity="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildVerbosity.Diagnostic]">
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="Verbosity"
                Type="InArgument(mtbw:BuildVerbosity)" />
  </x:Members>
  <Sequence>
    <mtbwa:WriteBuildMessage Importance="[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildMessageImportance.Low]"
                             Message="Test WriteBuildMessage Importance Low"/>
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

Comment: I did have to set my verbiosity to high on my messages, but I didn't have to refresh the build template.

Comment: A little follow up... I DID have to refresh the process template for the logging message to appear.
Thanks Gerard.

Comment: A little further follow up... Neither setting it to high or refreshing worked for me in TFS /VS 2012. I had to set the logging verbosity to Normal in the Queue Build parameters tab for it to show at all.